# Python class wont add to objectStore

Tags: python

for some reason when I try to add an object to a dictionary in a class, where the dictionary belongs to another class and objects are added/removed by class functions it always seems to fail adding.

Heres the datahandler :

```
class datastore():
    def __init__(self, dict=None):
        self.objectStore = {}
        self.stringStore = {}
        if dict is not None:
            self.objectStore = dict

    def __addobj__(self,obj,name):
        print("adddedval")
        self.objectStore[name] = obj

    def __getobject__(self,name):
        _data = self.objectStore.get(name)
        return _data

    def __ripobj__(self,name,append):
        if isinstance(append, object):
            self.objectStore[name] = append

    def __returnstore__(self):
        return self.objectStore

    def __lst__(self):
        return self.objectStore.items()
```

and heres the trigger code to **try** to add the item :

```
if self.cmd=="addtkinstance-dev":
        print("Adding a tk.Tk() instance to dataStore")
        #$$ below broken $$#
        _get = datastore.__dict__["__returnstore__"](self.dat)
        _get["test-obj"] = tk.Tk()
        datastore.__init__(self.dat, dict=_get)
        #--------------------------------------------#
        tool(tk.Tk(), "test-obj", datastore())
```

and also heres the **init** for the class that **trys** to add the object

```
class cmdproc(tk.Tk, datastore):

    def __init__(self,lst,variable_mem,restable):
        self.pinst = stutils(lst,restable,variable_mem)
        self.vinst = varutils(variable_mem,lst,restable)
        self.tki = tkhandler()
        self.dat = datastore(dict=None)
        datastore.__init__(self, dict=datastore.__returnstore__(self.dat))
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.lst = lst
        self.vdat = variable_mem
        self.restable = restable
```

please help this is *seriously* baffling me

(note that tkhandler dosn't have to do with anything)

Comment: I'd start by not naming your variables `dict`, shadowing built-ins is bad.

Comment: I changed dict to dictl

Comment: Could you post a complete ruunnable version of your code somwewhere like on http://codepad.org/ for easier/debuging/reading?

Comment: fixed it. If you notice, I keep redefining objectStore in __init__. surprised you didnt notice that